# Consulta ao MySQL com PDO não retorna dados

Tags: php, pdo

Tenho o seguinte problema. Desenvolvi um class PHP para um site que estou criando e em uma dessa funções estou tendo problema com o PDO. Ao dar o comando `SELECT` utilizo a função rowCount() para verificar se obteve resultados e o resultado obviamente é 0 rows. Eu já testei a QUERY e os includes e está funcionando normalmente.

Código da função:

```
public function search($s) {
    $db = $this->db;
    $find = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`,`coverofpost`, `date` FROM `posts` WHERE title LIKE '% :tl %' OR tags LIKE '% :tags %' OR post LIKE '% :post %'");
    $find->bindValue(":tl", $s, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $find->bindValue(":tags", $s, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $find->bindValue(":post", $s, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $find->execute();
    if ($find->rowCount() > 0) {
        $this->mountArray();
        while ($data = $find->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($this->id, $data['id']);
            array_push($this->type, $data['type']);
            array_push($this->title, $data['title']);
            array_push($this->cover, $data['coverofpost']);
            array_push($this->time, $data['date']);
        }
        $this->makeUrls();
        $this->makeArray();
        $this->postArray['status'] = true;
    } else {
        $this->postArray['status'] = false;
    }
    return $this->postArray;
}
```

O retorno é sempre `postArray['status'] //false`

Comment: Remova as aspas simples da consulta e passe os `%` no `bindValue()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A consulta não deve retornar resultados mesmo devido à aquelas aspas simples e aos coringas (`%`). Ou seja as aspas simples vão anular seu placeholder, ao invés de procurar `%termo digitado%` vai procurar `%:tl%`.

Para resolver remova as aspas simples e passe os conringas em `bindValue()`

Mude sua consulta para:

```
SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`,`coverofpost`, `date`
FROM `posts` WHERE title LIKE :tl OR tags LIKE :tags OR post LIKE :post
```

E os binds para:

```
$find->bindValue(":tl", '%'. $s .'%',  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$find->bindValue(":tags", '%'. $s .'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$find->bindValue(":post", '%'. $s .'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Em todos os `LIKE`s tem espaços (`LIKE '% :tl %'`), se foram intencionais adicione eles no bind.

```
$find->bindValue(":tl", '% '. $s .' %',  PDO::PARAM_STR);
espaço extra--------------^        ^--------------espaço extra
```

Comment: Resolveu. Muito obrigado!